# How can I use PsExec to install software on a remote computer

Tags: windows-7, psexec

Here are some details

1. Remote PC may not have an admin user.
2. Software is located on a network share that is accessible to all users.
3. PsExec is on the Admin machine

I've tried doing this but I get "Invalid directory" or "The system cannot find the path specified"

```
psexec \\REMOTEPC1 -w "C:\temp\installRF" "setup.exe /unattended=true /quiet=true /allowShutdown=false /add="FaxUtil,FaxCtrl" /rightFaxServer="faxserver1" /log:whyme"
```

Comment: Try rremoving the outmost pair of quotes from around setup and it's arguments.

Comment: i  did that and I get "The system cannot find the path specified". In command prompt, I am in the directory where the setup.exe is located. I don't know what the -w C:\temp\installRF is suppose to do

Comment: Read the docs. [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) - "-w directory Set the working directory of the process (relative to the remote computer)."

Comment: Where is setup.exe located? Is it on the remote machine?

Comment: its located in 2 locations. On the Target Machine, it's a network drive that is X:\Software\App1\setup.exe OR it can also be located via UNC path \\Server\Folder\App1\setup.exe

Comment: Try using `X:\Software\App1\setup.exe` in place of `setup.exe`. You must specify the full path to a program that is already installed on a remote system if its not on the system's path.

Comment: I tried that and same thing. "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Ok. Put quotes around just "X:\Software\App1\setup.exe". For now remove the -w stuff. Like this: `psexec \\REMOTEPC1 "X:\Software\App1\setup.exe" /unattended=true /quiet=true /allowShutdown=false /add="FaxUtil,FaxCtrl" /rightFaxServer="faxserver1" /log:whyme`

Comment: There is a vbs file in the installation folder. The vbs file has   oWshSh.Run "msiexec /i """ & sRunPath & "\RightFax Product Suite - Client.msi"" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress RUNBYRIGHTFAXSETUP=2 ADDLOCAL=""FaxUtil"" RFSERVERNAME=""SERVER1"" /qn /log ""C:\RfInstLog.txt""",0,True (however there is also a bat file that uses the setup.exe)

Comment: <shrug> I don't know what any of that does. If you run just `psexec \\REMOTEPC1 "X:\Software\App1\setup.exe"` does that work?

Comment: Or even `psexec \\REMOTEPC1 -w "X:\Software\App1" "X:\Software\App1\setup.exe"`?

Comment: I did that too and directory invalid. I also tried with the -u and -p flags to specify a domain user and password

Comment: Then I have no more ideas :/

Comment: I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations when installing applications remotely:

1) Will the installation require user interaction? 
2) Which user are you using to install the software?
3) Does the same user who you are using to install the software have the drive mappings and/or access to read the network store data?

Keeping that in mind, I recommend the following approach.

1. Create a script to copy the entire installation folder to the local system
2. Launch the installer application locally using the system account

I have some code I built with powershell a while back, here are the relevant lines of code you would be interested in:

```
    $computername=read-host "type in a computername"
    mkdir \\$computername\c$\MyAppInst
    copy-item  "X:\Software\App1\setup.exe"  "\\$computername\c$\MyAppInst"
    start-process "psexec.exe" -args "-accepteula -s -d -i 0 \\$ComputerName wscript.exe C:\MyAppInst\install.vbs" -passthru
```

I've built my own vbscript wrapper before to kick start the application installation because I don't think psexec can handle all of the install switches properly.

In my case, we were required to run a USMT (scanstate) backup remotely. Here is the vb code we used (scraped with identifying company information). I like to use the escape character of the double-quotation mark in vb (which is chr(34)) to make it easier to troubleshoot. Another great reason why I put everything into a variable is that I can wscript.echo that variable and see exactly what's being run.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
fileExecutablePath=chr(34) & "C:\Desktop Tools\USMTv2\scanstate.exe" & chr(34)

fileExecutableSwitches=" " & chr(34) & "\\server\migration_data\" & objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("COMPUTERNAME") & chr(34) & " /c /localonly /ue:MYDOMAIN\* /ue:" & objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("COMPUTERNAME") & "\*" & " /uel:7 /config:" & chr(34) & "C:\Desktop Tools\USMTv2\config.xml" & chr(34) & " /i:" & chr(34) & "C:\Desktop Tools\USMTv2\migapp-CompanyAppsOnly.xml" & chr(34) & " /i:" & chr(34) & "C:\Desktop Tools\USMTv2\migdocs-Company.xml" & chr(34) & " /l:" & chr(34) & "\\server\migration_data\" & objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("COMPUTERNAME") & "\" & objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("COMPUTERNAME") & "_usmtBACKUP.log" & chr(34) & " /v:13 /targetWindows7"

return=objShell.Run(fileExecutablePath & fileExecutableSwitches, 0, true)

wscript.echo "Your local data has been backed up. This data will be transferred to your new computer. Anything you now save locally will not be transferred."
```

Comment: Can you share your VBScript wrapper and relevant code? It sounds like you have this nailed down

Comment: In my instance, I was actually doing a USMT scanstate: